# Invertibility of $X_1'M_2X_1$ where $M_2=I-X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X_2'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I will be very grateful if someone helps me.

**Notation**: for any matrix of full column rank $Z$, define $P_Z=Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$ and $M_Z=I-P_Z$.

> **Claim**: suppose that $X$ is a $T\times K$ with full column-rank and $T>K$. Partition $X$ as
>   $$
> X=[X_1\quad X_2]\quad\text{with}\quad X_1\text{ is }T\times K_1 \text{ and } X_2 \text{ is }T\times K_2.
> $$
>   Then, $X_1'M_2X_1$ is invertible where $M_2=M_{X_2}$.

---

**Attempt**: I know various properties of the projection matrices $P$ and $M$ (e.g. symmetry, idempotency, mutual orthogonality). I also tried to prove by contradiction: suppose that there is $v\neq 0$ ($v$ is $K_1\times 1)$ such that $X_1'M_2X_1v=0$. Then
$$
0=v'X_1'M_2X_1v=v'X_1'M_2M_2X_1v=v'X_1'M_2'M_2X_1v=|M_2X_1v|^2\implies M_2X_1v=0.
$$
But now I can't continue because $M_2$ is singular: $M_2$, which is $T\times T$, has trace $T-K_2$ and eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ and so must have $0$ determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's proceed your logic. Assume for some $v\ne0$ $M_2X_1v=0$; Let denote $a=X_1v$. Since $X_1$ has the full column rank we have $a\ne0$. On the other hand 
$$
M_2=I-X_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^T=I-X_2 X_2^+
$$
In order be orthogonal to matrix $M_2$ vector $a$ mus have the form $X_2 b$. So we have 
$$
X_1 v=X_2 b 
$$
This contradicts with the full column rank of $[X_1,X_2]$.

Comment: +1, I'm not familiar with the particular notation $X_2^+$ but I understand your argument. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $X_2^+$ is pseudo inverse of the matrix. Just FYI.